# Kerberos error when trying to connect to remote Oracle database using ODP.NET

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2015, kerberos, odp.net, server-explorer

this is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49264094/how-to-uninstall-deprecated-oracle-data-provider). I am trying to use ODP.net in Visual Studio 2015 to connect to a remote Oracle 11gr2 server. The specific reason is for SSRS reports.

I have installed this version of ODT/ODAC, as recommended by Visual Studio: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/whatsnew/vs2012welcome-1835382.html (for more info, please see my previous question).

Without even opening up a solution, on the landing page of VS2015 I tried using the ODP.net driver by using Server Explorer and trying to "Add Connection". I am able to select the ODP.net managed and unmanaged drivers. However, when I try to "test connection" I get a Kerberos error:

[image]

The error message reads "NA Kerberos5: Authentication handshake failure at stage: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccessIOP.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found."

I have tried following these guides: 
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/installODPmd.htm#ODPNT8152
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E56485_01/win.121/e55744/featConnecting.htm#ODPNT8270

But it seems my problem is a lot more basic: I simply can't test the connection using the Server Explorer (i.e. I have no project/solution to put the `IOP.dll` in). I did however try putting the `IOP.dll` into the GAC, which also did not fix anything.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: H, there were some older issues with Kerberos and ODP.NET managed. Can you please uninstall all the ODAC software you installed and then reinstall using this 12.2.0.1.1 release: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odacmsidownload-2745497.html

Comment: Wow thanks for replying @ChristianShay! I will certainly pass this info along to my team

Comment: If they still have the problem after upgrading, reply here and we'll look into it further :)

Comment: Hi @ChristianShay, I did as you suggested but am now getting a different error however. When I try the live preview I get the error message "An attempt has been made to use a data extension oracle that is either not registered..."

Comment: Do you think installing a "fuller" version of ODAC again will fix the issue? The version you linked is very lightweight at 60 mb (and importantly, does not seem to create an Oracle home/client in the way that other ODAC installers have)

I am specifically referring to this question for the suggestion to reinstall ODAC:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39776069/ssdt-in-visual-studio-2015-oracle-connection-issue?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Thank you for any followup!

Comment: For clarity: this is the error message I am shown https://ibb.co/dBMfXS