# An attempt has been made to use a data extension 'ORACLE' error

Tags: .net, oracle, reporting-services

I installed SSRS 2013, and made a report and deployed it into SSRS server. My source database Oracle ,and I also have Oracle client and .net data provider on the same server that SSRS is installed.

When I tried to view published reports on the server the following error is raised:

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
>   An attempt has been made to use a data extension 'ORACLE' that is
>   either not registered for this report server or is not supported in
>   this edition of Reporting Services. (rsDataExtensionNotFound)

Could anybody cam help me out of this?

Comment: is this helfpul https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39776069/ssdt-in-visual-studio-2015-oracle-connection-issue

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to Moudiz's link for help. You need to pay attention client will use 32bit, and Server will use 64 bit, so you need to  install two version to test. You could refer to [Oracle Connection Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/oracle-connection-type-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017)  and [Configure Oracle data source for SQL Server Reporting Services (SSDT and Report Server)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2018/03/26/configure-oracle-data-source-for-sql-server-reporting-services-ssdt-and-report-server/)for details.

Zoe

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue with PBI Report Server. It ended up being that the ORACLE provider was commented out in the `rsreportsserver.config` file.

1. Open your rsreportsserver.config file as an administrator. Microsoft has [documented the locations here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/rsreportserver-config-configuration-file?view=sql-server-ver16). In my case it was found in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Power BI Report Server\PBIRS\ReportServer\rsreportserver.config`.
2. Locate the `<Extension Name="ORACLE"...` node and check if it’s commented out. If it is, uncomment it. [image]
3. Save the file
4. Restart the PowerBI Report Server Service / SQL Reporting Server Service.

Hopefully this has resolved it.